# How does AES secure streaming work at a high level?

Tags: javascript, security, encryption, video-streaming, aes

Essentially, I'm trying to understand what is required to develop software to:

a. stream video
b. stream video securely.

For example, right now I know that I can play a video in the browser by placing the file somewhere and putting that link in the video tag.

But that is neither streaming, nor secure.

So, what is required to achieve streaming, and then security on top of that?

I'm looking for an explanation like so.. this is me guessing what might be required:

1. create a video

2.a. encode that video to some format that makes it a streaming video?

2.b. or, create a manifest file for the video and split the video into little pieces on the server?... (I evidently don't get this bit)

3. Then whatever I have on the server, I somehow encrypt?
4. On the client side, I need js to consume/decrypt that video/manifest before dynamically passing something (what?) to the video tag?

As you can, there's a lot of gap in my knowledge. What am I missing?

Comment: Define "secure". You mean it can't be intercepted in transit or you mean only authorized viewers will be able to see it?

Comment: Actual video streaming uses RTSP, which uses an HTTP-like request/response protocol for meta-data before actually streaming the content.  I think it supports TLS too.  Might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Video streaming can be done with 2 open standard technologies:

- [RTSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol);
- [WebRTC](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/.).

Both links contain starting information and examples of implementations.

If I were you I would focus on video streaming itself and you could pick the security aspect from generic info about secure web development. Streaming itself should be enough to keep you busy for quite a while and it will guide your next steps. Perhaps you shall be interested about performant secure streaming by then (i.e. hardware accelerated encryption).